# Filtering REST queries by multiple parameters

Tags: rest

I have no problems getting a REST query to return the expected result set when I use a single clause-

```
http://website/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$filter= StartDate ge datetime'2014-01-01T00:00:00Z'
```

but when I try to add a second parameter

```
& Odata__EndDate le datetime'2013-12-31T00:00:00Z'
```

it ignores the second parameter. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`&` symbol could not be used in `$filter` query option expression.

Replace `&` with `and` operator, for example:

```
$filter=(StartDate ge datetime'2014-01-01T00:00:00Z') and (Odata__EndDate le datetime'2013-12-31T00:00:00Z')
```

### References

- [Working with folders and files with REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx)